# Distinct 1-Step-Difference between two dates

Tags: javascript, typescript

**Some Background:**

I have data points (current day + 5 days ahead, in 3-hour steps (e.g. 22pm, 1am, 4am, 7am...)) which i want to sort/group by date into arrays (one for each date).

My first attempt was to simply calculate the difference of the two date objects in date like

`(datapoint.getTime() - today.getTime())/ millisecondsPerDay`.
That did not work, because i get fractions of days.

Then i went with `Math.ceil()` and `Math.floor()` on the results, but that of course (i have been looking at my code for a while, so my brain didn't recognize the flaw then) didn't work, too, because it would put the current day and parts of the next day into the same group (22 pm + 3 hours is not on the same day, though the difference is < 1 day).

Then i did day comparison like

```
let diff = tmp.getDate() - today.getDate()
```

the problem with that approach is, that when i'm at the end of the month and a datepoint is in the next months, i get (relatively) high negative values which i can't use as array indices (e.g. `[0,1,2,4,5,-27]`).

**The Question**

How do calculate the difference between two dates in distinct day-steps while regarding change of month?

Comment: You've described two problems: 1. "I have data points ... which i want to sort/group by date into arrays," and 2. "How do calculate the difference between two dates in distinct day-steps..." Keeping in mind the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), which of these are you asking about?

Comment: @JordanRunning Well... i asked one question. But i'll clarify the first problem as background information.

Comment: Please add an example with desired result - for me its absolutely unclear what you try to accomplish. What is wrong with fraction of days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dates are in milliseconds you can try this. Divide both by (24 * 3600 * 1000) and take the Math.floor() - that will give you the amount of full days. Then simply subtract target result from today result.

So,

```
mils_in_a_day = 24 * 3600 * 1000
today_in_days = Math.floor(today_in_mils / mils_in_a_day)
target_date_in_days = Math.floor(target_date_in_days / mils_in_a_day)
difference_in_days = target_date_in_days - today_in_days
```

Then to sort you can do smth this for each example

```
results = {}
results[difference_in_days] = target_date_in_days
```

and end up with a hash like this

```
{ 
  '1' : [12356, 123457, 123458], 
  '2' : [234567, 234568, 234569]
}
```

Where the keys represent the difference in days and the values are the arrays of original timestamps. You can then call `sort()` on each of the arrays to sort timestamps within days.

I'm sure it's not the most efficient way but that should give you the idea.

Comment: Expanding on this, you should be able to take the result of tmp - diff and use getHours() on that.